# Problems building nofib/fibon

Tags: haskell, ghc

When building the `fibon` benchmarks under the `nofib` benchmarks suite I got several permission denied messages, one as below:

```
== make boot - --no-print-directory;
 in /h/ywang30/nofib/fibon/Hackage/Bzlib
------------------------------------------------------------------------
//     Codec/Compression/BZip/Stream.hsc
make[3]: execvp: //: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [Codec/Compression/BZip/Stream.hs] Error 127
Failed making boot in Bzlib: 1
```

I'm building the suite as advised on the [GHC wiki page](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/RunningNoFib). By default `fibon` is not included in the build and I edited `mk/boilerplate.mk` (line 35) to include it (which works for the `parallel` benchmarks). I know that, from the wiki the correct way to do that should be editing `../mk/build.mk` and `../mk/config.mk`, but there's no line involving nofib in either file. What am I doing wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Do you mean "By default `fibon` is not included in the build ..."?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean